# What is the meaning of translating "in the direction of a vector"?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I got a exercise to find the complex function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that does a translation in the direction of the vector (-3,5) in the real plane. The question says it's not a linear transformation but I don't know what it means by "translate in the direction of a vector (or, maybe, "towards a vector", the question is not in English)". It also says that it's represented algebraically as a complex function

$f(z)= \alpha z+ \beta$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$

I thought in using a matrix such as

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & p_1 \\0 & 1 & p_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} x_1+p_1\\ x_2+p_2\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$

But I don't know if this is right or how to get $f$ from it.

Answer (score 2):

To translate in the direction of a vector is simply to add this vector to everyone. So your map would be $f(z) = z + (-3+5i)$.

Comment: But can't I find a homothety + rotation (that will be linear) that does the same than it?

Comment: @A.Mello No, because a linear map always preserves the origin, whereas a nontrivial translation like this one clearly doesn't.